# Determine if $f(z)$ has a branch point where it is not analtyic?

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-points

Let us say that you have a function $f(z)$ how would determine if the point $z=z_0$ is a branch point of $f(z)$ (and its order) given that $f(z)$ is not analytic at this point.

(For reference: this question (and the links in the answer) [Showing $1$ is not a branch point for $f(z) = z^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032069/showing-1-is-not-a-branch-point-for-fz-z2) gives the case where $f(z)$ is not analytic at $z_0$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}$Suppose $g:\Cpx \to \Cpx$ is holomorphic. Loosely, branch points of $f = g^{-1}$ correspond to critical points of $g$: If $g(w_{0}) = z_{0}$ and $g'(w_{0}) = 0$, then $f = g^{-1}$ has a branch point at $z_{0}$.

For example, the squaring function $g(w) = w^{2}$ has a critical point at $w_{0} = 0$, so the square root $f(z) = \sqrt{z}$ has a branch point at $0 = z_{0} = g(w_{0})$.

In more detail, if $g(w_{0}) = z_{0}$ and $g'(w_{0}) = 0$, then there exists a unique integer $n \geq 2$ and a unique holomorphic function $h$ with $h(w_{0}) \neq 0$ (and therefore non-vanishing in some neighborhood of $w_{0}$) such that
$$
z = g(w) = z_{0} + (w - w_{0})^{n}\, h(w)
$$
for all $w$ in some neighborhood of $w_{0}$. The (necessarily multi-valued) inverse function $f$ defined by
$$
f(z) = w_{0} + \left[\frac{z - z_{0}}{h(w)}\right]^{1/n}
$$
satisfies $f(z_{0}) = w_{0}$ and $g\bigl(f(z)\bigr) = z$ for all $z$ in some neighborhood of $z_{0}$, and has a branch point of order $n$ at $z_{0}$.

Conversely, if $g'(w_{0}) \neq 0$, the inverse function theorem guarantees $g$ is locally a biholomorphism, i.e., has a (single-valued) holomorphic inverse in some neighborhood of $z_{0} = g(w_{0})$.

Since all these considerations are local, similar remarks hold for holomorphic mappings between arbitrary Riemann surfaces.

Comment: This answer was written in response to your earlier (deleted) question, but I trust it addresses the current version.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Is it possible to do a similar treatment in the cases where $g$ is not holomorphic (at the point of interest)

Comment: Possibly. :) What conditions on $g$ are you willing to assume? (The preceding argument handles the point at infinity in the Riemann sphere, and poles of meromorphic functions, if that helps.)

Comment: These conditions are fine, just for clarity, what about the case when $g$ itself is non-singular e.g. for $f=\sqrt{z^2+1}$?

Comment: If $g$ does not have a critical point at $w_{0}$, then a branch of inverse $f$ near $z_{0} = g(w_{0})$ is single-valued (and holomorphic).

Answer (score 0):

Here are my steps to **finding the branch points** of the function $f(z)$

1. Set $w=f(z)$
2. Differentiate both sides w.r.t $w$:$$1=f'(z) \frac{dz}{dw}$$ $$\frac{dz}{dw}=\frac{1}{f'(z)}$$
3. Find the values of $z$ for which the above is $0$. These are our branch points.

   4. Set $t=\frac{1}{z}$ and use the above method to find the branch points of $f(t)$. If $t=0$ is a branch point, then our original function has a branch point at $\infty$.

To find the **order of the branch point** at $z=z_0$.

*Method 1*

Find the first time derivative is not 0, i.e. that $$\frac{d^n z}{dw^n}\ne0$$ and $$\frac{d^k z}{dw^k}=0 \forall k<n$$ (all evaluated at $z=z_0$).
Then the order of this branch point is $n$.

*Method 2*

Sub $z=z_0+re^{i\theta}$ into the original function and physically see how many times  you have to take $\theta$ round to get back to your original value. If you can take it $n+1$ times round the order is $n$.